# What is the typical usage of View > Server Explorer vs View > SQL Server Object Explorer?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, server-explorer

What is the connection (no pun intended) or relation (NPI) between the Server Explorer and SQL Server Object Explorer "Views" (no pun intended) available from Visual Studio?

When I want to examine a database I can select View > Server Explorer, and the main categories/folders are:

```
Azure
Data Connections
Servers
SharePoint Connections
```

In Data Connections, there are items such as duckbill.PlatypusData.dbo, which contain the following folders:

```
Tables
Views
Stored Procedures
Functions
Synonyms
Types
Assemblies
```

If, OTOH, I select View > SQL Server Object Explorer, there are these two categories of items:

```
SQL Server
Projects
```

Beneath SQL Server, duckbill has these folders:

```
Databases
Security
Server Objects
```

In Databases.PlatypusData there are these subfolders:

```
Tables
Views
Synonyms
Programmability
Service Broker
Storage
Security
```

So, unique to the View > Server Explorer > Data Connections > [database name] are these items:

```
Stored Procedures
Functions
Types
Assemblies
```

Unique to View > SQL Server Object Explorer > SQL Server are these items:

```
Programmability
Service Broker
Storage
Security
```

The commonality between the two "Views" are:

```
Tables
Views
Synonyms
```

So, for example, to view/run Stored Procedures I need to use View > Server Explorer. What is the "cutoff point" between usage of these two Views. Is one for a certain type of developer/development, and one for something else? Are they both intended for distinct "Roles" (NPI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view the view from Visual Studio is just an extension to the traditionally available SQL Management Studio. I think both of them have their own uses and purposes. Visual Studio would be typically used by application programmer to quickly query the data and examine the objects in SQL Server. Or by a DevOps person to view various other things like the EventLog or Services Statuses under the Server Node.

Whereas, SQL Management Studio would be used by SQL only person. Who does not have anything to do with application development as such.

I dont think there is any cutoff point as such. Its a option which is there. However, seeing the development Microsoft is making i wont be surprised if they will merge two together some day. I remember back in old days there was Query32.exe which was used to query SQL Server data outside of SQL Management studio.